# Shiny app - select unique values from a column that is common across a list?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app which reads multiple similar datasets. I have it reading in the files via a source.R file using
files_to_read <- dir_ls("Data")

and this works great, creating a list, with each dataset as a tibble. I can see that is will allow me to select a dataset on the sidebar using:

```
 data_choices <- data_name[c(1:5)]

 selectizeInput(inputId = "Data",
                          label = "Choose data to plot",
                          choices = data_choices,
                          selected = "d_raw",
                          multiple = TRUE)
                      ),
```

when the app is run.

However, I want to also be able to select the data to view by year, which is a common column across all the datasets and has a range of unique values (also common across each dataset).

I have tried:

```
data_year <- lapply(data_name(function(x), unique(x))
```

and

```
year_choices <- unique(data_name$yyyy)
```

but it won't give me a list of unique years to select from when running the app? (there is a selectizeInput within the UI, similar to above)

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: I would be very helpful if you could supply a workin minimal example of the whole app and not just parts of the server code

Comment: I messed about with it so much I made a real mess of it and scrapped it, but thanks for taking the time to write